# chrome console click function does nothing on a paritcular website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console

I went to this website

```
http://getlike.io
```

and i wanted to do a simple click using the chrome console on that blue button top

[image]

I used chrome console and I right clicked on the element > inspect > found element on chromes console > copy selector and I got the selector. Here is the selector for the blue button `#header > div.top > div > div > div.col-md-2.col-3 > a`

I just add it to a jquery tag since jquery is already loaded `$("#header > div.top > div > div > div.col-md-2.col-3 > a").click();`

and it does nothing i have tried using javascript as well and still click does nothing..the odd thing is I am always using same way to click with console and it always works but this website..seems like they somehow understand i am performing click action using chrome console?
does anyone knows why on this website not possible to click on some elements ?

Comment: did the same using js , try in dev tools console .... : `const btn = document.querySelector('a.btn.hidden-sm-down'); btn.click();`

Comment: is it beause you used querySelector that it can perform click?thanks for the answer i accept it as coorrect answer

Comment: not that because of querySelector may be the exact node is not selected in your case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the Jquery selector is an array.
So you have to use the index to point to the item you want to work with.

In this case, because there is only one item with the specified selector, you can use 0 index to access the button in the array.

```
$("#header > div.top > div > div > div.col-md-2.col-3 > a")[0].click()
```

Comment: Oh thanks that was useful.i didn't notice this element is an array.right now i double checked and you are right it's an array of elements

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it's a `<a>` tag that doesn't have a click event attached to it. On a button, there is usually a method linked with `onClick` or `addEventListener` or `$.on("click")` that is triggered when you click or use the `.click()`.

If you look in the dev console, in the event listener of that element, there is nothing attached to it.